# Error 42 when trying to access a struct templates members

Tags: d

I'm trying to use the Gl3n (https://bitbucket.org/dav1d/gl3n) but 
I keep getting error 42 whenever I try this:

```
alias Vector!(float, 2) vect2;
vect2 position;
position.x = 2.0f; //This is what causes the error
```

I looked into how the struct was implemented and x is an alias 
for a get/set function that interacts with the array that stores 
the values for the vector. I've tried something like this:

```
alias Vector!(float, 2) vect2;
vect2 position;
position = vect2(0.0f, 0.0f);
```

However, both methods give the same error:

```
Error 42: Symbol Undefined pure nothrow @property @safe void 
gl3n.linalg.Vector!(float, 
2).Vector.set_!('x').set_(float)    C:\Users\CP\Documents\Visual 
Studio 2010\Projects\D\STDS\    

Error 42: Symbol Undefined 
_D4gl3n6linalg16__T6VectorTfVi2Z6Vector6__initZ
```

I have the module linalg imported like this at the top:

```
import Gl3n.linalg; //Gl3n is the folder the source files are in
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Error 42 is the linker error (optlink).

I don't remember the linker flag, but you need to tell the linker where the library is (gl3n.lib I suppose).

You can use pragma(lib, "gl3n.lib") at the top of your main file assuming gl3n.lib is located in the directory you are compiling from.

Comment: "Undefined symbols" are pretty much always linker errors in languages which use the C linking model.